# Overloading == operator C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

i did an overloading of the + operator but now i wanna do overloading of == operator of 2 lengths (may or may not be the same length) and return the respective results. How do i do it? Do i need to use bool for ==?

//what i did for overloading + operator to get new length out of 2 different lengths

```
Length operator+ (const Length& lengthA){       

    int newlengthMin = min, newlengthMax = max;

    if (lengthA.min < min)
        newLengthMin = lengthA.min;
    if  (lengthA.max > max)
        newLengthMax = lengthA.max;

    return Length(newLengthMin, newLengthMax);
}
```

Comment: There can only be one result. Note the operator == is a comparison (or should be for consistency). So it should return true/false depending on the equality comparison of two lengths.

Comment: oh aright so in a sense it returns the answer automatically for u based on its comparison right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the simple case, use `bool operator==(const Length& other) const`. Note the `const` - a comparison operator shouldn't need to modify its operands. Neither should your `operator+`!

If you want to take advantage of implicit conversions on both sides, declare the comparison operator at global scope:

`bool operator==(const Length& a, const Length& b) {...}`

Answer (score 6):

Use bool and make sure to add `const` as well.

```
bool operator==(const Length& lengthA) const { return ...; }
```

You can also make it global, with two arguments (one for each object).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the equality operator is a comparison operation. You'll return a boolean indicating the correct condition. It would be something like this:

```
bool operator== (const Length& lengthA, const Length& lengthB) const {
    return (lengthA.min == lengthB.min) && (lengthA.max == lengthB.max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/94-overloading-the-comparison-operators/

Cheers!

Comment: Uhm... it's the logical `and` operator. You shouldn't be tackling operator overloading without that kind of previous knowledge. Try taking the tutorial from the beginning!

Comment: too big a bite out of a delicious pie u cant resist...haha thnx anyway